# Ajax post call seems to work, still throws error?

Tags: ajax, asp.net-web-api

Although the code works as expected it throws

"An error occurred whilst trying to contact the server: 200 parsererror SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input"

The success branch is never called but the data arrives to the api.

Should I be concerned and solve it or it probably won't cause problems elswhere? Thank you for your help.

```
       <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#Save").click(function () {
                var data2send = JSON.stringify("test");
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'https://localhost:44348/api/products/PostProduct',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: data2send,
                    contentType: 'application/json',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function (data2send) {
                        console.log(data2send);
                    },
                    error: function (jQXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        console.log("An error occurred whilst trying to contact the server: " + jQXHR.status + " " + textStatus + " " + errorThrown);
                        console.log(data2send);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Controller

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("PostProduct")]
    public void Post([FromBody] string obj)
    {
        Product.prod.Add(new Product() { ProductId = 12, ProductName = obj, Price = 12 });
    }
```